# Does `csh` have the Bash equivalent of `set -o nounset`?

Tags: bash, shell-script, csh

I have some legacy `csh` code that is having issues and I think the issue is related to unset environment variables that need to be set but aren't being set.

**Does `csh` have the Bash feature `set -o nounset`?**

I ask because I thought to myself "`csh` has `set echo` which is like Bash's `set -o xtrace` and so maybe `csh` also has the other Bash feature `set -o nounset`".

Comment: That's the default in `csh`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Stéphane [answered in the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332209/does-csh-have-the-bash-equivalent-of-set-o-nounset#comment584645_332209):

> That's the default in csh!

To add a reference point, the [csh manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/csh) says, under Variable substitution:

...

> Except as noted, it is an error to reference a variable which is not set.

...